# WebStorm Meteor debugger stopped working after reinstalling OS

Tags: meteor, webstorm, remote-debugging

The log I got in the terminal is shown below. It used to work with the same configuration before. After reinstalling OS I'm facing issues.

> ```
>  [ 274053]  ERROR - debugger.scripts.DirectoryInfo - WebStorm 9.0.4  Build #WS-139.1803.34 
>     [ 274053]  ERROR - debugger.scripts.DirectoryInfo - JDK: 1.8.0_111 
>     [ 274053]  ERROR - debugger.scripts.DirectoryInfo - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
>     [ 274053]  ERROR - debugger.scripts.DirectoryInfo - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
>     [ 274054]  ERROR - debugger.scripts.DirectoryInfo - OS: Linux 
>     [ 274054]  ERROR - debugger.scripts.DirectoryInfo - Last Action: Debug 
>     [ 274054]  ERROR - ins.io.ChannelExceptionHandler - null 
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.jetbrains.javascript.debugger.scripts.DirectoryInfo.removeEntry(DirectoryInfo.java:119)
>       at com.jetbrains.javascript.debugger.scripts.DirectoryInfo.removeChild(DirectoryInfo.java:105)
>       at com.jetbrains.javascript.debugger.scripts.ScriptManager.doRemoveScript(ScriptManager.java:107)
>       at com.jetbrains.javascript.debugger.scripts.ScriptManager.removeScript(ScriptManager.java:100)
>       at com.intellij.chromeConnector.debugger.V8DebugProcess$MyDebugEventListener.scriptCollected(V8DebugProcess.java:464)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:88)
>       at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.access$100(EventDispatcher.java:34)
>       at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher$1.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:68)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.scriptCollected(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jetbrains.v8.V8ScriptManager.scriptCollected(V8ScriptManager.java:197)
>       at org.jetbrains.v8.EventMap.handleResponseWithHandler(EventMap.java:37)
>       at org.jetbrains.v8.V8CommandProcessor.acceptNonSequence(V8CommandProcessor.java:57)
>       at org.jetbrains.v8.V8CommandProcessor.acceptNonSequence(V8CommandProcessor.java:16)
>       at org.jetbrains.rpc.MessageManager.processIncoming(MessageManager.java:103)
>       at org.jetbrains.v8.V8CommandProcessor.processIncomingJson(V8CommandProcessor.java:32)
>       at org.jetbrains.v8.StandaloneV8Vm$2$2.consume(StandaloneV8Vm.java:60)
>       at org.jetbrains.v8.StandaloneV8Vm$2$2.consume(StandaloneV8Vm.java:57)
>       at org.jetbrains.v8.connection.V8MessageDecoder.readContent(V8MessageDecoder.java:130)
>       at org.jetbrains.v8.connection.V8MessageDecoder.messageReceived(V8MessageDecoder.java:88)
>       at org.jetbrains.v8.connection.V8MessageDecoder.messageReceived(V8MessageDecoder.java:14)
>       at org.jetbrains.io.SimpleChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead0(SimpleChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:20)
>       at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>       at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:182)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:886)
>       at io.netty.channel.oio.AbstractOioByteChannel.doRead(AbstractOioByteChannel.java:147)
>       at io.netty.channel.oio.AbstractOioChannel$1.run(AbstractOioChannel.java:45)
>       at io.netty.channel.ThreadPerChannelEventLoop.run(ThreadPerChannelEventLoop.java:52)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:834)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
> ```

Comment: Did you re-install Java? other tools that you were using before?

Comment: This must be fixed in one of the following WebStorm versions -- please check [WebStorm 2016.3 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP).

Comment: Looks as if the debugger is not compatible with your Chrome. You are using very age-old WebStorm version (that, BTW, provides no support for Meteor at all - I wonder how you made it work for you before re-installing the OS?)

Comment: re-installed java, I was not using any other tool before. Debugger was working just fine. I even tried 2016.3 EAP. Now the error is not seen. But also the debugger wont work.